# Add missing linux package for electron source code compilation

Tags: linux, electron, chromium, xcb, remote-control

Electron : 4.0.0

OS : Ubuntu 18.04.3 TLS

I am trying to make few changes to the **electron's source code** which is compiled following the link below:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-linux#prerequisites

My requirement calls for the need of linux XCB Test Api's **xcb_test_fake_input_checked** function. But, when I include <xcb/xtest.h> in the c++ file I have created , I get **fatal error: 'xcb/xtest.h' file not found.**

The corresponding package **libxcb-xtest0-dev** is already present.

I tried the command **locate xtest.h** . It gives **/usr/include/xcb/xtest.h**

But, other header files like xproto.h which are properly included in the .cc file, are present under the electron build folder(Path: electron/src/build/linux/debian_sid_amd64-sysroot/usr/include/xcb/xproto.h).

I assume, the reason for the fatal error is that electron linux build folder doesn't have xtest.h.

How can I install this libxcb-xtest0-dev dependency for my electron linux build, so that xtest.h gets included properly?